# I need a pop-up in Excel when I click on a particular row

Tags: excel, vba

So the idea is, when I click on any cell belonging to a particular column a popup should come in which I can enter two values - both of which should be auto-populated next in separate columns next to the actually clicked column in the same row.

I know this sounds trivial but I'm hopeless in Excel Macros - is this even possible?

Comment: what particular column, are you not able to be more specific?

Comment: Lets say, I click on E3. A pop up should come with two fields on filling which the values should get reflected in F3 and G3

Comment: Is it column E or just E3?

Comment: The Entire Column E.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the below code and do right click on sheet tab and select view code and paste it.

Close the VBA window (Alt+Q to close VBA window) and return to that sheet and check.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column = 5 Then
    Dim sF1 As String, sF2 As String

    sF1 = InputBox("Enter Field 1 Value", "Field One Value Req.")
    sF2 = InputBox("Enter Field 2 Value", "Field Two Value Req.")

    With Target
        .Offset(, 1).Value = sF1
        .Offset(, 2).Value = sF2
    End With
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Worked like a charm. How do I add this macro to all the sheets in the workbook?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding allowing the code to work **in all the sheets of that workbook** question, remove the given code from the sheet module and apply the below code in Thisworkbook module as described below.

**To Add Excel VBA Code to a Workbook / This Workbook Module**

1. Copy the code that you want to use
2. Select the workbook in which you want to store the code
3. Hold the Alt key, and press the F11 key, to open the Visual Basic
   Editor
4. In the Project Explorer, find your workbook, and open the list of
   Microsoft Excel Objects
5. Right-click on the ThisWorkbook object, and choose View Code Where
   the cursor is flashing, choose Edit | Paste

---

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column = 5 Then
    Dim sF1 As String, sF2 As String

    sF1 = InputBox("Enter Field 1 Value", "Field One Value Req.")
    sF2 = InputBox("Enter Field 2 Value", "Field Two Value Req.")

    With Target
        .Offset(, 1).Value = sF1
        .Offset(, 2).Value = sF2
    End With
End If

End Sub
```